# Laravel 5.4 and PHPBB3.2 Session

Tags: php, laravel, session, phpbb3

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and PHPBB3.2. I install this package: https://packalyst.com/packages/package/tohtamysh/laravel-phpbb-bridge After I configure everything I try to login but was unsuccessful. I check username, password, API key/url but everything was fine. Then I found that problem is with the session. So how can i use PHPBB3.2 session in Laravel? I search in google for a solution but without success.

Comment: *Then I found that problem is with the session*, PHPBB and Laravel uses different cookie and uses different session handler (remember laravel can have database-driven session storage?). Perhaps you can post the code you have tried. if you used [PHP's session directly](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) do some trick, but not advisable.

Comment: @BagusTesa I already posted the link with the whole code.